# Eclipse Paho MQTT Golang publish subscribe to AWS IOT returns EOF error when running as separate process on same machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, mqtt, paho

I am using Go v1.17.2 on Linux to connect to AWS MQTT using the [paho.mqtt.golang](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang) library v1.4.1. I am basing my code on this sample from [EMQX](https://www.emqx.com/en/blog/how-to-use-mqtt-in-golang) using TLS with the certificates provided by AWS IOT Core.

When I run the publish and subscribe code in the ***same*** go program as per the above example from EMQX everything works and I can see the following output:

```
2022/08/11 19:47:42 Connected
Subscribed to topic: topic_1
2022/08/12 13:47:42 Received message: Message 0 from topic: topic_1
2022/08/11 19:47:43 Received message: Message 1 from topic: topic_1
...
2022/08/11 19:47:51 Received message: Message 9 from topic: topic_1
```

However, if I run the publish code in one go program (using go run) and run the subscribe in a ***separate*** program on the same machine at the same time, then the subscribe fails on each message with an EOF error:

```
2022/08/11 19:54:50 Connected
2022/08/11 19:54:54 Connect lost: EOF
...
2022/08/11 19:54:59 Connected
2022/08/11 19:54:59 Connect lost: EOF
```

Here is the publish code

```
client := mqtt.NewClient(opts)
if token := client.Connect(); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
    log.Fatalln(token.Error())
}

publish(client, *topic)
client.Disconnect(250)
...

func publish(client mqtt.Client, topic string) {
    num := 10
    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
       text := fmt.Sprintf("Message %d", i)
       token := client.Publish(topic, 0, false, text)
       token.Wait()
       time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

and the subscribe code

```
client := mqtt.NewClient(opts)
if token := client.Connect(); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
   log.Fatalln(token.Error())
}

sub(client, *topic)
time.Sleep(11 * time.Second)
client.Disconnect(250)

...

func sub(client mqtt.Client, topic string) {
    token := client.Subscribe(topic, 1, nil)
    token.Wait()
    log.Printf("Subscribed to topic: %s", topic)
}
```

If I run the subscribe code only, and use the AWS IOT console to publish some message that also works

```
2022/08/11 20:25:27 Connected
2022/08/11 20:25:27 Subscribed to topic: topic_1
2022/08/11 20:25:29 Received message: {
  "message": "Hello from AWS IoT console"
} from topic: topic_1
2022/08/11 20:25:30 Received message: {
  "message": "Hello from AWS IoT console"
} from topic: topic_1
```

It looks like the issue is to do with having two connections open to AWS IOT/MQTT at the same time.

Here is my MQTT client options config

```
opts := mqtt.NewClientOptions()
opts.AddBroker(fmt.Sprintf("tls://%s:%d", *host, 8883))
opts.SetClientID("basicPubSub")
opts.SetTLSConfig(tlsConfig)
opts.SetDefaultPublishHandler(messagePubHandler)
opts.OnConnect = connectHandler
opts.OnConnectionLost = connectLostHandler
```

Answer (score 1):

This was due to me using the same client ID for the publish and subscribe code.

The Eclipse Paho docs explain this via a link to the [MQTT specifications](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc384800405)

> If validation is successful the Server performs the following steps.
>
> 1.If the ClientId represents a Client already connected to the Server then the Server MUST disconnect the existing Client
> [MQTT-3.1.4-2].

I used a different client ID for each program and it works.
**Note:** The AWS IOT policy must allow for each client ID to connect (allow **iot:Connec**t action)

Comment: I put this at the top of ["Common Problems"](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang#common-problems) because it's an issue that everyone is likely to encounter at some point. If you have any thoughts on improvements to the docs that would have helped you find this more quickly then please [raise an issue](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang/issues).

Comment: Thanks for that. I think the docs could specifically mention the clientID. I will raise a change for the doc when I get a chance.